# Extract Table's Data(including BLOB and CLOB Field's Data) from Source Database and import data to Destination Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, blob, clob

Regularly I extracted (Source Database) the table’s data as a flat file (.DAT) via spooling in SQL*Plus Tool in Oracle database and Import the extracted data into Destination database (client Database and importing is the Client work).

Here my problem is some of the tables (more than 20 tables) are having BLOB and CLOB fields

Example Table Name: TEST_BLOB_CLOB

```
ID      Name    Address    Blob_COL     Clob_COL
-------------------------------------------------------------
1001   Sanjay   Chennai   Audio File    more than 32k text values
1002   Ragav    Mumbai    PDF File      more than 32k text values
1003   Vijay    Delhi     Word File     less than 32k text values
1004   Sam      Nagpur    Txt file      more than 32k text values
```

Note:

- In BLOB_COL some files are loaded in the database itself and some files are locally kept in the server computer (only path has been indicated)
- I have googled and searched here too everywhere I am seeing only single image or audio or pdf file extc has been extracted from BLOB field like "SELECT BLOB INTO l_blob FROM test_blob_clob WHERE id = 1005;" in PLSQL procedure.
- I dont need a single blob/clob data.
- I need to extract all BLOB/CLOB data with related to the rest of the filed as like as combined data

Import the data in destination database is not my job, My job is only Extract the table's data as a flat file (.DAT)

Here Table are created like both BLOB and CLOB in single table and BLOB alone in another table and CLOB alone in some other table.

Please any one help me how I need to extract all the table's data as well as all BLOB and CLOB fields’ which has mentioned in the example table and I need to give the extracted data to client.

Thanks
Sanjay R

Comment: do you need export the files that are stored externally and you have links to them only in your tables?

Comment: Your asking about the Files locally copied in the server computer only the paths are links., Yes, I need to extract Both the way, 1. Internally loaded files in tables(database). 2. Locally copied in computer only path will be identified in the blob fields. 2nd method client can do, they will copy the files into the same directory of their destination server and the links will be in blob field. Second one is easy, but 1st method, which is database table is stored the files and combined with the whole tables record with (clob field) i need to extract

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use a flat file format, rather than a data pump export?

Comment: it's not a problem to export LOB objects that are stored in database - you need use expdp utility. with files where you have links only - it sounds as a separate task

Comment: we are cloning the application from source to destination, documentation levels are completed and client requiring all the data(Oracle table) in flat file format only, client will import these flat files into their database tables.  This is the normal process we are following for all the table's data, but I dont know how to extract BLOB and CLOB Table value and I am new to this DBA field. can u pls explain the data pump export?

Comment: Thanks "ARE"., I will check that EXPDP data pump utility whether applicable to my process or not.